# Issue filtering DT datatable with horizontal scroll in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In my Rshiny dashboard I want to display a wide table (>15 columns) in a DT DataTable having filters on top and horizontal scrolling on. When I now want to apply the filter all columns are suddenly visible in the area outside the width of the table.

Here's an example that shows the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("results", width = 300)
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$results <- DT::renderDataTable(
      mtcars,
      filter = "top",
      options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                     dom = 'Brtip')
    )
  }
))
```

Is this an unfixed problem in DT or is there a way how I could fix this in the given code example?